# Remove quotes from column name

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume i have following table:

```
create table t1(
    clid number,
    category varchar2(100)
);

insert into t1 values(1, 'A');
insert into t1 values(1, 'B');
insert into t1 values(2, 'A');
insert into t1 values(2, 'C');
insert into t1 values(3, 'A');
insert into t1 values(3, 'B');
```

I need to pivot this table and count the number of times per each each CLID value. So in order to achieve this I use following code:

```
select * from t1
pivot(
    count(item)
    for item in('A', 'B', 'C')
)
```

And get the result:

```
CLID  'A' 'B' 'C'
1     1   1   0
2     1   0   0
3     1   1   0
```

Everything is great except quotes in names of new columns. I've tried the next code:

```
alter table t1 rename column 'A' to A
```

And it raises following error:

```
Error starting at line : 537 in command -
alter table t1 rename column 'A'
Error report -
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So my question is how can I rename column name which is in quotes (and in this way get rid of quotes)?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you okay with pivot and still looking for an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column name seems to be `category`, not `item`.

So:

```
SQL> select * from t1
  2  pivot(
  3      count(category)
  4      for category in('A' a, 'B' b, 'C' c)            --> this
  5  )
  6  /

      CLID          A          B          C
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          0
         2          1          0          1
         3          1          1          0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just using conditional aggregation?

```
select sum(case when item = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
       sum(case when item = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
       sum(case when item = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as C       
from t1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach would not be convenient enough sine in real data I have hundreds of items, so it would take too much time to put all that items in conditional aggregation.